# VPN Access in SL

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am implementing VPN ACCESS using java Soflayer API.
These APIs are found, but there is no example to implement it.

1. http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_User_Customer
2. SoftLayer_Network_Service_Vpn_Overrides

How can i get the available VPN types such as SSL, PPTP etc using API ?

If you guide me what to start or provide me any reference example, it will be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There are only "SSL" ,"PPTP" and "SSL and PPT"  for users, and there is not any method to get the VPN types

You can know what type of VPN has the customer by reviewing the attributes:
"pptpVpnAllowedFlag"
"sslVpnAllowedFlag"

if both are true, so the customer has "SSL and PPTP" if only "pptpVpnAllowedFlag = true" so the customer only has PPTP enabled and so.

also you can see the property "vpnManualConfig" in order to know if his configuration is manuaul or automatic

In order to know the subnets enabled for the user (in case it is manual configuration) you can see the property "overrides"

this RestFul resquest will give you the information you need:

```
GET https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_User_Customer/$UserID/getObject?objectMask=mask[pptpVpnAllowedFlag, sslVpnAllowedFlag,  vpnManualConfig, overrides]

note: replace $UserID with the id of the user
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

This is a script to automate VPN Access for multiple user using [SoftLayer API Java Client](https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-java):

```
package Users;

import com.softlayer.api.ApiClient;
import com.softlayer.api.RestApiClient;
import com.softlayer.api.service.Account;
import com.softlayer.api.service.network.Subnet;
import com.softlayer.api.service.network.service.vpn.Overrides;
import com.softlayer.api.service.user.Customer;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
/**
 * Add Vpn Access for Multiple users
 *
 * This script creates VPN Access for Multiple Users.
 *
 * Important Manual Page:
 * http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Service_Vpn_Overrides/createObjects
 * http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Network_Service_Vpn_Overrides
 * http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getUsers
 * http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_User_Customer/getOverrides
 *
 * @license <http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License>
 * @authon SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
 * @version 0.2.2
 */
public class AddVpnAccess {
    /**
     * This is the constructor, is used to create VPN Access
     */
    public AddVpnAccess(){
        // Declare username and api key
        String username = "set me";
        String apiKey = "set me";
        // Get Api Client and service
        ApiClient client = new RestApiClient().withCredentials(username, apiKey);
        // Declare SoftLayer_Account and SoftLayer_User_Customer services
        Account.Service accountService = Account.service(client);
        Customer.Service customerService = Customer.service(client);
        Overrides.Service overrideService = Overrides.service(client);
        // Define the usernames from users that you wish to create VPN Access
        String [] users = {"user1", "user2", "user3"};
        // Define VPN Type options: "None", "SSL", "PPTP", "SSL & PPTP"
        String vpnType = "SSL & PPTP";
        // Define the networks identifiers from subnets to create the overrides
        String [] subnets = {"10.62.42.64", "10.104.213.192", "10.110.39.64"};

        // Define an array to Build the template with all SoftLayer_Network_Service_Vpn_Overrides objects to be deleted.
        List<Overrides> overrides = new ArrayList<Overrides>();

        // Building Customer template for VPN Access
        Customer templateObject = new Customer();
        templateObject.setPptpVpnAllowedFlag(false);
        templateObject.setSslVpnAllowedFlag(false);
        if(vpnType.contains("SSL"))
        {
            templateObject.setSslVpnAllowedFlag(true);
        }
        if(vpnType.contains("PPT"))
        {
            templateObject.setPptpVpnAllowedFlag(true);;
        }

        try{
            // Getting users
            List<Customer> userList = accountService.getUsers();
            // Getting subnets
            List<Subnet> subnetList = accountService.getSubnets();

            // Setting VPN Access
            for(String user : users)
            {
                for(Customer accountUser : userList)
                {
                    if(accountUser.getUsername().equals(user))
                    {
                        // Setting init parameter
                        customerService = Customer.service(client, new Long(accountUser.getId()));
                        boolean result = customerService.editObject(templateObject);
                        System.out.println("User: " + accountUser.getUsername() + " VPN Access: " + result);
                        if(templateObject.getSslVpnAllowedFlag() == true || templateObject.getPptpVpnAllowedFlag() == true)
                        {
                            for(String subnet : subnets)
                            {
                                for(Subnet accountSubnet : subnetList)
                                {
                                    if(accountSubnet.getNetworkIdentifier().equals(subnet))
                                    {
                                        Overrides objectOverride = new Overrides();
                                        objectOverride.setUserId(new Long(accountUser.getId()));
                                        objectOverride.setSubnetId(new Long(accountSubnet.getId()));
                                        overrides.add(objectOverride);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if(templateObject.getSslVpnAllowedFlag() == true || templateObject.getPptpVpnAllowedFlag() == true)
            {
                boolean result = overrideService.createObjects(overrides);
                System.out.println("Have been set the overrides successfully? " + result);
            }
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        new AddVpnAccess();
    }
}
```

> Updated

My apologizes, apparently there is an issue with [SoftLayer API Client for Java](https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-java) at the moment to create VPN Overrides, I have opened an issue:

https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-java/issues/31

However, I can provide the same idea using [SoftLayer API PHP client.](https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-api-php-client)

Php script

```
<?php
/**
 * Add Vpn Access for Multiple users 
 * 
 * This script creates VPN Access for Multiple Users.
 * 
 * Important manual pages:
 * @see http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Service_Vpn_Overrides/createObjects
 * @see http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Network_Service_Vpn_Overrides
 * @see http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getUsers
 * @see http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_User_Customer/getOverrides
 * @see http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/Object-Filters
 * 
 * @license <http://sldn.softlayer.com/wiki/index.php/license>
 * @author SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com> 
 */
require_once '\vendor\autoload.php';

// Your SoftLayer API username.
$username = "set me";

// Your SoftLayer API key.
$key = "set me";

// Define the usernames from users that you wish to create the overrides
$users = array("user1", "user2", "user3");

// Define VPN Type options: "None", "SSL", "PPTP", "SSL & PPTP"
$vpnType = "SSL & PPTP";

// Define the networks identifiers from subnets to create the overrides 
$subnets = array("10.126.46.128", "10.5.214.192");

// Create a SoftLayer API client object for "SoftLayer_Account", "SoftLayer_User_Customer" and "SoftLayer_Network_Vpn_Overrides" services
$accountService = \SoftLayer\SoapClient::getClient('SoftLayer_Account', null, $username, $key);
$customerService = \SoftLayer\SoapClient::getClient('SoftLayer_User_Customer', null, $username, $key);
$overridesService = \SoftLayer\SoapClient::getClient('SoftLayer_Network_Service_Vpn_Overrides', null, $username, $key);

// Declare an object filter, to retrieve subnets specified in $subnets array
$filterSubnets = new \stdClass();
$filterSubnets -> subnets = new \stdClass();
$filterSubnets -> subnets -> networkIdentifier = new \stdClass();
$filterSubnets -> subnets -> networkIdentifier -> operation = "in";
$filterSubnets -> subnets -> networkIdentifier -> options = array();
$filterSubnets -> subnets -> networkIdentifier -> options[0] = new stdClass();
$filterSubnets -> subnets -> networkIdentifier -> options[0] -> name = "data";
$filterSubnets -> subnets -> networkIdentifier -> options[0] -> value = $subnets;
$accountService -> setObjectFilter($filterSubnets);

// Get Subnets
$receiptSubnets = $accountService -> getSubnets();

// Declare an object filter, to retrieve users with the specific username specified in "$users" array.
$filter = new \stdClass();
$filter -> users = new \stdClass();
$filter -> users -> username = new \stdClass();
$filter -> users -> username -> operation = "in";
$filter -> users -> username -> options = array();
$filter -> users -> username -> options[0] = new stdClass();
$filter -> users -> username -> options[0] -> name = "data";
$filter -> users -> username -> options[0] -> value = $users;
$accountService -> setObjectFilter($filter);

// Get users 
$receiptUsers = $accountService -> getUsers();

// Build template
$templateObject = new \stdClass();
$templateObject -> sslVpnAllowedFlag = false;
$templateObject -> pptpVpnAllowedFlag = false;
if(strpos($vpnType, "SSL") !== false)
{
    $templateObject -> sslVpnAllowedFlag = true;
}
if(strpos($vpnType, "PPTP") !== false)
{
    $templateObject -> pptpVpnAllowedFlag = true;
}

try {
    // Define an array to Build the template with all SoftLayer_Network_Service_Vpn_Overrides objects to be deleted.
    $overrides = array();
    $subnetFlag = false;

    // Setting VPN Access
    for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($receiptUsers); $i++) {
        $customerService -> setInitParameter($receiptUsers[$i] -> id);
        $result = $customerService -> editObject($templateObject);
        echo "VPN Access set for user: " . $receiptUsers[$i] -> username . "\n";
        if($templateObject -> sslVpnAllowedFlag == true || $templateObject -> pptpVpnAllowedFlag == true)
        {
            for ($j=0; $j < sizeof($receiptSubnets) ; $j++) {
            array_push($overrides, array("subnetId" => $receiptSubnets[$j] -> id, "userId" => $receiptUsers[$i] -> id));
                }
            $subnetFlag = true;
        }
    }
    // Setting subnets
    if($subnetFlag)
    {
        $result = $overridesService -> createObjects($overrides);
        print_r("The VPN overrides were created?: " . $result);
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e -> getMessage();
    }
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks It helps a lot.. :)

Comment: The code returns an error. The message is "Error: com.softlayer.api.ApiException$NotFound: Function ("createObject") is not a valid method for this service.(code: SoftLayer_Exception_Public, status: 404)" .

Comment: The createObjects() is working with PHP client ? If so, can you provide me the RestURL information ?

Comment: Please, see my new answer to create vpn overrides through Restful calls

Answer (score 0):

Try the following Rest request:

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Network_Service_Vpn_Overrides/createObjects

Method: Post

{  
   "parameters":[  
      [  
         {  
            "subnetId":1139909,
            "userId":498265
         }
      ]
   ]
}
```

Replace: $user, $apiKey, 1139909 and 498265 with you own information.

To get user identifiers:

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Account/getUsers
Method: Get
```

To get subnet identifiers:

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Account/getSubnets
Method: Get
```

References:

- [SoftLayer_Network_Service_Vpn_Overrides::createObjects](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Service_Vpn_Overrides/createObjects)
- [SoftLayer_Account::getUsers](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getUsers)
- [SoftLayer_Account::getSubnets](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getSubnets)

Comment: Thanks. There was a bug in Java client library. This issue was resolved by fixing Java Lib.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to your question:

**How can I set ID of override ?**

The following request will help with this:

```
https://$username:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_User_Customer/$userId/getOverrides
Method: Get
```

Replace: $username, $apiKey and $userId with your own information.

Regarding to this:

> The deselection of Grant Access is not saved in control.softlayer.com.
>   When reopen VPN Access List, there is still Grant Access checked.

This is a known issue, the fix will be released as soon as possible, my apologies for the inconveniences

**References:**

- [SoftLayer_User_Customer::getOverrides](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_User_Customer/getOverrides)